# Taxonomy page wpml dropdown not working

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, plugin-wpml

I have created the custom post type with the taxonomy product-categories.
I have installed wpml and added the menu with the custom category. When the menu created using the custom post type category with taxonomy is clicked . Then the WPML language selector in the header is not displaying the language list. Please guide me how to sort this please

The Language selector dropdown is listed  in all the pages but not listing in the Taxonomy pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default language selector is pretty crap TBH.

I created this function using jQuery, you will have to amend to fit your template.

```
function language_selector(){
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0&orderby=code');
    $current_lang = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
    if(!empty($languages)) { ?>
        <div id="language_list">
            <div class="current">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME; ?>" /> <?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME; ?> <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <ul>
        <?php foreach($languages as $l): ?>
                <?php if($l['active']) continue; ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $l['url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $l['country_flag_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $l['native_name']; ?>" /> <?php echo $l['native_name']; ?></a>
                </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var languageSelector = $('#header .additional .language');
                var currentLanguage = $('.current', languageSelector);
                var languagesSelection = $('ul', languageSelector);


                var toggleLanguageSelector = function() { 

                    if( !languagesSelection.is(':visible') ) {

                        currentLanguage.addClass('active');

                        languagesSelection.slideDown(300);

                    } else {

                        currentLanguage.removeClass('active');
                            languagesSelection.hide();
                    }

                };

                currentLanguage.bind('click', toggleLanguageSelector);

            });
        </script>
<?php
    }
}
```

Then implement like so:

```
    <div class="language">
        <span><?php _e('Choose Language', 'theme_text_domain'); ?></span>
        <?php language_selector(); ?>
    </div>
```

Try this and see if it works, obviously I will leave the CSS to you.